# Flatten grid coordinates to find display order.

Tags: calculus

I have a grid measuring (3 * 3) for example (though there may be more rows, there will always be 3 columns only), and i need to find the display order of a particular item, given it's x, y position.

All positions start at 0.

For example expected output:

Item Position = 0, 2
Output: 2

Item Position: 1, 1
Output: 4

Item Position: 2, 0
Output: 6

Item Position: 3, 2
Output: 11

What formula would I need for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, at least your thoughts, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For item position $m,n$ the output is $3m+n$.